# Google Chrome how to check stored sessions

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, session-variables

I am setting sessions in my PHP script, and I would like to check values of stored SESSION variables in google chrome. How can I client-check saved values?

Comment: you can't. the only session-related data chrome will ever receive from PHP is a cookie with the session's ID's. Actual session data (e.g. `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';` is kept purely on the server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Important Points:**

1. Session always stored on the server.
2. If you want to see stored session value use **echo  $_SESSION['value'];** in your script.
3. If you would like to check values of store data accessible use **cookies**.

Comment: Do you mean checking `echo $_SESSION['value']` in Chrome console?

Comment: @Blaise Not in chrome, check it in your php script as `echo $_SESSION['value']` is a PHP syntax

Answer (score 4):

Session data is stored on the server only, and cannot be accessed by the client. If you'd like to store data accessible by the client and the server, use cookies.

Comment: How would you check the session data via the server?

Answer (score 1):

I do this :

```
$carrito = $_SESSION['detalle'];
echo '<script>console.log('.json_encode($carrito).')</script>';
```

It works fine in every case.